# What simple topological properties of conic sections can be explored?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, metric-spaces, conic-sections, metric-geometry

In the framework of my science fair project I am working on conic sections in different metric spaces. What simple topological properties/operations and so can I explore on them?

---

Edit:

To clarify, I am considering these spaces - Chebyshev, discrete, maybe a Paris space ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedgehog_space)).

I define conic sections via their distance definition, i.e. for example ellipse is defined as $d(X, F_1) + d(X, F_2) = 2a$, and then I try to get the shape of it from definitions of metric.

Comment: Could you please add details about which metric spaces you're considering, and how you define a "conic section" in these spaces? (I didn't vote to close, but tend to agree the current wording is difficult to address substantively.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang done.

Comment: FYI, there seems to be some research on conic sections in the taxicab metric (google "conic sections" and "taxicab" together).